# Difficulties with JSON using Python's requests library

Tags: python, json, python-requests

When attempting to scrape producthunt,

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'www.producthunt.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.producthunt.com/', headers=headers)
```

I found that the returned response doesn't have a valid string to convert to json. After trying to replace the type of quote with response.text.replace() and to return the json with json.loads(re.sub(r'^jsonp\d+(|)\s+$', '', response.text)), I still get the same error.

Error:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Thoughts?

Comment: changing to `'Accept':'application/json'` to the header may help.

Comment: ^ You're accepting XHTML or images as a response

Comment: Also note: `producthunt.com` alone is just HTML... There's no magic way to convert any web page to JSON

Comment: Unfortunately not, I tried that already :(

Comment: Show us the full error traceback and the full code to raise the error. Also show us the status code returned and the beginning of the response body.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has nothing to do with JSON

You're requesting a webpage, not a JSON API

```
$ curl -sH 'Accept: application/json' https://www.producthunt.com/ | head -c 200
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><title>Product Hunt – The best new products in tech.</title><link rel="canonical" href="https://www.producthunt.com/"/><meta name="description" content="Product %
```

You should use `beautifulsoup` or `selenium-webdriver` instead to extract HTML content, then parse to JSON, depending on your needs

---

And in reality, the site uses GraphQL at `https://www.producthunt.com/frontend/graphql`

Comment: hm, so what slightly throws me off is
```data = '${"operationName":"HomePage","variables":{"cursor":"NQ==","featured":true,"includePromotedPost":false,"visibleOnHomepage":true,"includeLayout":false},"query":"query HomePage($cursor: String, $postCursor: String, $featured: Boolean\\u0021, $includePromotedPost: Boolean\\u0021, $visibleOnHomepage: Boolean\\u0021)}'

response = requests.get('https://www.producthunt.com/frontend/graphql', headers=headers, data =data)

```

with the original headers just gives me an error of
```
{'status': 400, 'error': 'Bad Request'}
```

Comment: Not sure since I don't manage ProductHunt. I suggest using a GraphQL library in python rather than requests